# mail() function in PHP does not works in local system

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php mail() function on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342822/php-mail-function-on-localhost)

I am using php mail(). I have been working in my local system, I mean not a domain. is shows  php error as bellow

Error Message: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()

I tried this http://pastebin.com/SNcnPi5c to check but  does not works fine what i need to change?

Comment: read : http://in2.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means you have no SMTP server listening on port 25 on your localhost.

If you want to send mails, you will have to put valid SMTP configuration in your php config.

Answer (score 2):

Have you got a mail server running on your local machine? Otherwise you need to configure it in `php.ini`.

Comment: How can i configure the SMTP in php.ini my conficuration is like bellow. Where can i douwnload SMTP?                              SMTP :localhost,
smtp_port: 25,
sendmail_from: novalue,
sendmail_path: novalue

Answer (score 1):

You Have to put valid SMTP on your config in php.ini, Search for smtp servers around its plenty. Google has one. also jango. both free jango has trial

Comment: Thank you I will check and get you back