# Not receiving the mail

Tags: php, html

I want to create a contact form using **PHP mailing function**. I am learning the process by developing on a free web hosting provider. Here are my files:

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>HTML5 Contact Form</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="styles.css">
    </head>     
    <body>
        <div id="contact">
            <form class="contact_form" action="contact.php" method="post" name="contact_form">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                         <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                         <span class="required_notification">* Denotes Required Field</span>

                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="name">Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="John Doe" required />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="email">Email:</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="john_doe@example.com" required /> <span class="form_hint">Proper format "name@something.com"</span>

                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="message">Message:</label>
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="40" rows="6" required></textarea>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button class="submit" id="submit_btn" type="submit">Submit Form</button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### contact.php

```
<?php
    $field_name = $_POST['name'];
    $field_email = $_POST['email'];
    $field_message = $_POST['message'];
    $mail_to = 'babloopuneeth@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;
    $body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
    $body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
    $body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;
    $headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";
    $mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

    if ($mail_status) {
        ?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
            window.location = 'sample.html';
        </script>
    <?php
     } else { ?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to gordon@template-help.com');
            window.location = 'sample.html';
        </script>
    <?php
     } 
?>
```

I also have a **styles.css** file. I'm getting the alert box saying `Thank you for the message`. But I'm **not getting a mail**.

**Can anyone help me? Where am I going wrong?**

Comment: Have you checked your Junk folder?

Comment: Check in `Spam folder`. Did you get `else part` **alert** from `contact.php`?

Comment: @RohanKumar: Im getting alert of if part only. I even checked in spam folder.. IM not getting.

Comment: Have a look at mailq maybe your server is not configure

Comment: Have any of our answers solved your problem ? If so, please accept one! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your hosting service block port 25? I have tested it on my server and it works perfectly.

If you are using [000webhost](http://000webhost.com) then it does. That is the most common free service and they removed support for mail a while back.

Answer (score 2):

The free hosting service you're using may not allow this functionality (I would of thought it wouldn't) have you checked?

Also check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342822/php-mail-function-on-localhost):

Answer (score 1):

Please check your **hosting service**, I am sure your code is all good as I actually tested it and **it worked perfectly**. :) You may want to test it yourself on **http://goo.gl/sDIL6**. (I will keep it there for a few days..)

[image: Fill out the form]

---

[image: Received message]