# Can we not send email from localhost anymore?

Tags: php, email, localhost, sendmail.exe

I use newer xampp 1.8.3 and do the setting like the old one. I only changed the code in php.ini and sendmail.ini. And I use gmail to send emails from localhost.

Here is the changed code for php.ini:

```
//remove the semicolon
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

And here is changed code for sendmail.php:

```
defaults
logfile "C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.log"

# SMTP Gmail
account Gmail
tls on
port 465
tls_starttls off
tls_certcheck off
host smtp.gmail.com
from my-gmail-id@gmail.com
auth on
user my-gmail-id@gmail.com
password my-gmail-password

account default : Gmail
```

And here is the code for sending email:

```
<?php
    $to = "my-gmail-id@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Send Email";
    $msg = "Send Email From Localhost";
    mail($to, $subject, $msg);
?>
```

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplication of [php mail() function on localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342822/php-mail-function-on-localhost)

Comment: @OPatel no, it is successful, at [php mail() function on localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342822/php-mail-function-on-localhost) it says `Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()` but I don't have those errors. The problem is the email I sent is not in my gmail inbox.

Comment: u can use phpmailer for sent mail from localhost

Comment: @MayurKukadiya so we can't send email from localhost with the way I explained above?

Comment: i dont know about that but with phpmailer u can easy search multiple  demo and document for sent mail from localhost ..so i had suggest for that..