# php mail() from localhost

Tags: php, email

I've a website in localhost (WAMP) and I'm trying to send a mail. I've made the right configuration in the php.ini file but still error is showing.

[image]

[image]

I've already checked other topics in SO but none of the answers resolve my problem :( So if someone can help me, thank you ! :)

PS : I'm sending mail using PHP for the first time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php mail() function on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342822/php-mail-function-on-localhost)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send an email using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php)

Comment: Nice question !

Answer (score 0):

Your SMTP server requires authentication. Try adding auth configuration to your php.ini and restart the server:

```
auth_username=yourUsername
auth_password=yourPassword
```

Maybe an easier way to configure and send email would be to use 3rd party library, for example PHPMailer.

Here's a tutorial: https://www.smtp2go.com/setupguide/php_mailer/