# How to send message directly to inbox (gmail) from localhost?

Tags: wordpress, sendgrid, contact-form-7, email-spam

I'm trying to send the message using the contact form on local-host. However, I'm able to send it to my mail address, but it goes to the spam folder!

I used the SendGrid plugin and integrate it with the Contact form 7.

Expected: Message send to the main folder in Gmail address.
Actual Result: Message goes to the spam folder.

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595730/sending-email-from-localhost).

Answer (score -1):

You can use GMAIL SMTP Plugin. You need to just install the plugin and then get a GMAIL API and SECRET KEY. Put that into your plugin. 
for more check this post with video.

http://www.onlinemoneyidea.cf/2019/06/gmail-smtp.html